# Need to replace substring from string ignoring case

Tags: apex

Please find below code

```
String str = 'Hi {!Contact.FirstName} your phone number is {!Contact.Phone}';
```

I want to replace the string as follow

```
String str = 'Hi {!contact.firstName} your phone number is {!contact.phone}';
```

String is not fix so I can't put hard coded value in the replace and replaceAll functions

Please help .

Comment: Can you explain more the global probrem? I am understanding that you are sending and email from apex

Comment: No need to worry about case, Apex is not case sensitive. So it won't cause any error.

Comment: I am reading body of email from static resource and have to replace {!ContactFirstName } with actual value

Comment: @RohitMourya str = str.replace('{!contact.name}' , 'Ranjit') this is not working.

Comment: regex would be much efficient

Comment: `str.replace('{!contact.Firstname}' , 'Ranjit')`  you need to use `firstName` not `name`

Comment: whatever field it will , field are not fix , so just want a way where i can replace string ignoring case

Comment: You can first convert the string to lower case with  `toLowerCase()` method and then replace the string

Comment: The general problem of rendering merge fields can be resolved by rethinking the problem and using the `getMergedBody()` method of `Messaging.RenderEmailTemplateBodyResult` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert your string to lower cap with the below code

```
str = str.toLowerCase();
```

then replace the string

```
str.replace('{!contact.Firstname}' , 'Ranjit')
```